# specifying count with alias and group by month

Tags: php, sql, count, group

```sql
SELECT MONTHNAME(date_added) as month,
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests WHERE form_status = :approved) AS approved, 
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests WHERE form_status = :denied) AS denied, 
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests WHERE form_status = :completed) AS completed,
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests WHERE form_status = :pending) AS pending 
                    FROM requests WHERE req_dept = :req_dept GROUP BY month
```

the results isnt what i expected. I want to count form statuses and eventually group it by month but the result is it counts the same for every month. im using chartjs .

Comment: What if in the table data is being presented more than for one year? `2021 Feb count + 2022 Feb count = Feb count`, that's ok for you?

Comment: There are better ways to do this than with subselects. `SUM(form_status = :approved) as approved` - the result of the comparison, when used in a numeric context, is either 0 or 1, so you can easily sum those up.

Answer (score 0):

### Lets Try this :-

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT MONTHNAME(DATE_ADDED) AS MONTH,
CASE WHEN FORM_STATUS = :APPROVED THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS APPROVED, 
CASE WHEN FORM_STATUS = :DENIED THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DENIED, 
CASE WHEN FORM_STATUS = :COMPLETED THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS COMPLETED,
CASE WHEN FORM_STATUS = :PENDING THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PENDING 
FROM REQUESTS WHERE REQ_DEPT = :REQ_DEPT 
) SELECT MONTH, SUM(APPROVED) AS APPROVED, SUM(DENIED) AS DENIED, SUM(COMPLETED) AS COMPLETED, SUM(PENDING) AS PENDING
GROUP BY MONTH
```